# Not able to navigate when ajax calls are running

Tags: c#, jquery, ajax

In MVC application, I make 18 async ajax calls together but not able to navigate to any other page until all calls are done.

Wanted to abort these calls if we click on navigation links. Please let me know if I am doing anything wrong.

```
 $.ajaxSetup({
        beforeSend: function (xhr) {
            xhrpool[i++] = xhr;
            $(window).bind('beforeunload', function () {
                for(j=0; j<i; j++){
                    xhrpool[j].abort();
                }
            });
        }
    });
    // for each row test the method or service and get result
    $("#table tbody tr").each(function (index, el)
    {
        $.getJSON('@Url.Action("GetServiceCheckResult", "ServiceCheck")', { 'index': index }, function (result)
        {
```

Comment: You'd have better to request the server only once with all relevant datas instead of making 18 similar ajax calls

Comment: the browser will limit you to (6) concurrent calls to a domain. navigating away counts as a call

Comment: if you have many calls to make, I suggest websockets instead of ajax

Comment: This is a design smell.

Comment: 18 simultaneous ajax calls and you don't have a clue why the browser hangs :)

Comment: Can we not abort these calls on navigation ?